# Troubles showing different representations of a word

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm doing a word count with PySpark where one of the tasks that I need to handle is to show all the representations of one word (i.e. apple, Apple, aPPLe, etc.)

Currently, my code only shows the lowercased version of the word, but it counts all representations. I know this is because I lowercased all of the words in the text file at the beginning, but I'm not sure how to change it so that my wordReps will show all representations.

```
hussle = sc.textFile("SOME_TEXT_FILE")

def removePunc(x):
    bars = x.encode('utf-8')
    lowerBars = bars.lower()
    cleanBars = lowerBars.translate(None, string.punctuation)
    return cleanBars

words = hussle.flatMap(lambda x: removePunc(x).split())

total_words = words.count()

wordCount = words.map(lambda x: (x,1)).reduceByKey(lambda x,y: x + y).map(lambda x:(x[0],x[1],x[1]/float(total_words))).sortByKey(False)
wordReps = words.map(lambda word: (word.lower(), word)).reduceByKey(lambda word1, word2: word1 + " " + word2 if word2 not in word1 else word1)
wordsFinal = wordCount.join(wordReps)
```

My expected output should be something like:

```
'all' (4, 'all All aLL')
```

but rather, I'm getting:

```
'all' (4, 'all')
```

Comment: not sure about your parameters to `.translate()`. I think you just need the translation table as a parameter. But why do it that way when you could use `re.sub()` to replace specific characters. Also, why do you convert your string to a `bytes` type object with `.encode()`? Is that necessary?

Comment: @Todd I'm very new to Python, so some of the stuff that I'm doing might not make sense. I'm learning as I go. "string.punctuation" in the translate statement allows me to remove all punctuation rather than looking for specific characters. I'm strictly trying to count words and their representations at this moment.